# The playback failed to find the control with the given search properties error

Tags: c#, checkbox, coded-ui-tests

I'm new to coded UI testing, so I have such easy question:

let's say there is an application with main window(just one button that calls secondary window) and secondary window. In this secondary window is container for elements and checkbox inside. 
I'm trying to write a coded UI test where at first I will open main window, push button that calls secondary window, and in secondary window I want to check/uncheck checkbox(depends on it's default value).

If to run test where I'm not changing state of checkbox, it passes. But when I run this test and change state of checkbox, test fails and I get error :

> The playback failed to find the control with the given search properties... Search may have failed at 'id of the container' Pane as it may have virtualized children. If the control being searched is descendant of 'id of the container' Pane then including it as the parent container may solve the Problem.

And this container has set **AutomationProperties.AutomationId="id of the container"** so coded ui should find it, because it always the same.

When I have a look at UI Control Map, I can find a secondary window, but I cannot find that container(3rd party).

How can I solve this?

Comment: Many questions have been asked about how to handle this error message, both here on Stackoverflow and on other sites. Doing a web search will find lots of useful information. If you still have problems after doing some research then you could update this question to explain what you have tried and why it did not do what you want.

Comment: @AdrianHHH I've created Coded UI test, and it works when I do not use elements inside this Container. For example when checkbox is on window. But when element is inside, then test fails. Why it doesn't work? It can't get to this container. Why? I donno and that's why I'm asking

Comment: Much more information is needed to provide a solution. That is why I said to search the web for others who have the asked and solved the same problem. You should already have done a web search for "debugging coded UI tests" and similar terms, that should have found the **Debugging and troubleshooting" part of http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mathew_aniyan/archive/2010/02/11/content-index-for-coded-ui-test.aspx . This blog has lots of other very good information on Coded UI.

Comment: While I throw out a few possibilities: Are any of the search properties between the windows ambiguous? If both windows are titled "Window", coded ui may look for the control in the wrong window.  Does the state of check box change any values being used as search properties.  Try inspecting (inspect.exe) the controls in both states of the check box, try using the test builder to check control search properties also.  Sometimes hierarchy can differ depending on the inspection tool.  You can set the always search configuration.  If using record and play back, look at the designer. OutOfCharacters

Comment: Thank you for your time, the problem was with 3rd party container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with 3rd party container. Coded UI could not find DocumentWindow within TabbedMdiContainer.